# Exception when I try to create Database on my test, using TeamCity for CI

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, teamcity

In one of my test I need to create a SQL Express database and then populate it.

It's run fine on my machine but when TeamCity tries to run the very same test it throws the following exception:

```
Test(s) failed. System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException : Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
  ----> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'.
```

What could be causing this?

Comment: [Check this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dparys/archive/2009/09/17/create-database-permission-denied-in-database-master-my-fix.aspx) or [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1616515/sql-server-express-create-database-permission-denied-in-database-master)

Comment: what account is your teamcity agent running under? Does it run as a user that has permission?

Comment: I use this [script](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/addselftosqlsysadmin/) to solve the problem

Comment: @james [.]\System account

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this [script](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/addselftosqlsysadmin/) to give administrator permission to [.]\System user (which is team city agent account).

Answer (score 1):

In `Enterprise Manager-> Data Base`richt click on master db select `Properties` and add your `permission`